# Python pause & resume execution of multiple functions separately

Tags: python

I am working an image viewer using `tkinter` that is split into four frames each of which displays a picture separately. I want to implement the functionality of pausing a particular frame without causing the others to pause, I thought of binding keys to each frame using `pynput` say:

frame 1 -> 'a',
frame 2 -> 'b', etc.

Here is a function that passes the image path to another function that handles display of an image with a delay of 1 sec per image:

```
def pass_image(list_of_img_paths, delay):
    for path in list_of_img_paths:
        image_display_handler(path)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Four instances of `pass_image(list_of_img_paths, delay)` each will be attached to a frame, what I want to do is when I pause one frame on a particular picture the other 3 frames should continue executing, and I don't know how to proceed to get that. Kindly, don't spare any details.